# Two, completely independent, means exist to obtain the same answer

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-sequence

... one "local"; and one "global"

```
1)  1 +  1 =  2  
2)  2 +  1 =  4  
3)  3 +  2 =  9  
4)  5 +  3 = 17  
5)  7 + ?? = 32
```

Can you determine the correct answer and ***both means of obtaining it***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> 5

Obtained by

> consider question number is n, first number is a and second number is b, so a + b(n)  = c, so 7 + 5c = 32, 5c = 25, c = 5

Can obtained too through

> Fibonacci sequence

Comment: You need a second method of obtaining it — namely that rot13(gur frpbaq ahzoref sbyybj gur Svobanppv Frdhrapr).

Comment: @El-Guest does it mean this question consists 2 answers?

Comment: the question states that you need to find the correct answer **and both** ways of finding the correct answer.

Comment: @El-Guest I’m new here, even I have put you in the credit for my edit above but it doesn’t state there, what is ‘Summary of change’ column?

Comment: the summary of changes is found in the edit history (by clicking “Edited” x hours ago). Thanks for the credit, but you got most of the answer by yourself! All credit to you!

Answer (score -2):

> 1) 1 + 1 = 2-------1 + 1 + 1x0 = 1+1+0= 2  
>  2) 2 + 1 = 4 ------2 + 1 + 1x1 = 2+1+1= 4 
>  3) 3 + 2 = 9 ------3 + 2 + 2x2 = 3+2+4 = 9 
>  4) 5 + 3 = 17------5 + 3 + 3x3 = 5+3+9 = 17
>  5) 7 + 5 = 32------7 + 5 + 5x5 = 7+5+25= 32

The answer is

> 5.

Comment: Without an explanation it's not clear what mechanism you're proposing is at work here.  (Does the parenthetical expression *replace* the second operand, as would be required for your 5th line, or is it *added in as well* as required for the other lines? The same rule should apply for all lines, and yours doesn't...?) At best, this is a duplicate of the existing answer, but lacks an explanation of why you think it is correct—so is likely to be deleted as redundant. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: With your added explanation (of a sort), you should be able to see that 7+5+25 = **37** - invalidating your own answer.